# Change child item size inside custom panel

Tags: c#, wpf, panel

Currently I am trying to create my own custom panel e.g. WrapPanel, Grid, ... .
How can I change the size of the child item - after `.measure();` inside the panel?

My code looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace CustomPanel
{
    public class MyCustomPanel : Panel
    {
        public object Convertchild { get; private set; }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
        {
            Size childSize = new Size(availableSize.Width, double.PositiveInfinity);

            foreach (UIElement elem in InternalChildren)
                elem.Measure(childSize);


            return availableSize;
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            child.Arrange(new Rect(x, y, child.DesiredSize.Width + 20, child.DesiredSize.Height + 20));
            return finalSize;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe it's important. I want to give the childs a start with like this:

```
<local:MyCustomPanel>
    <Rectangle Name="Rectangle_1" Height="200" Width="100" Fill="Green"/>
    <Rectangle Name="Rectangle_2" Height="150" Width="100" Fill="Black"/>
    <Rectangle Name="Rectangle_3" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Orange"/>
    <Rectangle Name="Rectangle_4" Height="100" Width="150" Fill="Yellow"/>
    <Rectangle Name="Rectangle_5" Height="150" Width="150" Fill="Gray"/>
</local:MyCustomPanel>
```

Comment: You'll have to call `Arrange()` on all child elements in `ArrangeOverride`. See [How to: Create a Custom Panel Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-custom-panel-element)

Comment: @Clemens thanks for the answer. That was my bad. I deleted it unfortunately. I've edited it. The width and height wont't be 20px larger.

Comment: A Panel will not (and should not) change the size of its child elements when their size has been set explicitly (as you do by setting the Rectangles Width and Height).

Comment: @Clemens I want to create something similar to a WrapPanel. All items should get an start value. The rest witdh of the row width should be divided to the other elements. So it's not possible?

Comment: WrapPanel does not change the size of its children. Besides that, if a Panel should resize its child elements (e.g. like a Grid), you should not set their Width and Height.